# Why is an AccessViolationException thrown when I call an imported C++ function from C# code?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport, access-violation

I have been reading many threads about the topic but I have not been able to find a solution to my problem yet.

From my C# code, I try to call a C++ function by using `DllImport`. Unfortunately, I do not have the C++ code, but the header file gives information about the function:

```
ABCD Initialize
(
  IN FLOAT a  
  , IN DWORD b  
);
```

ABCD is defined in the header file as well:

```
#define EFGH extern "C"
...
#define ABCD EFGH __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT WINAPI
```

In C# code, I try to to call the Initialize function like this:

```
[DllImport("path.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern UInt32 Initialize([In] float a, [In] UInt32 b);
...
Initialize(50.0f, 0);
```

According to [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke) there is no need for marshalling for the data type `float`, and instead of `DWORD` I can use `UInt32`. For the return type, `HRESULT WINAPI`, I use the data type `UInt32` and in my understanding there no need for marshalling as well? *(I also tried to use other data types for parameters and the return value, but always got the same exception)*

For the DllImport attribute, many possibilities for `CharSet` and `CallingConventions` have been tested, but I had no success. When declaring the function, I also tried both variants, with and without the `[In]` attribute for the parameters.

When the function is called, an exception is thrown:

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

Am I missing something here? What could be my next steps to call the function successfully?

Thank you.

---

Here is the full C# code. As said, I do not have the code that was used to build the .dll file. Also I am not allowed to share the dll.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  class Program
  {
    [DllImport("path.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern UInt32 Initialize([In] float a, [In] UInt32 b);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Initialize(50.0f, 0); // <- throws System.AccessViolationException
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As stated here, that code is correct. I bet that you transcribed something when you changed it from the real code. Present a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately I am not allowed to share the .dll file, so I can not provide a reproducible example. The C# code is nearly complete, the namespace consists of a single class with a Main function that only calls `Initialize(50.0f, 0);`.

Comment: Of course you can share a reproducible example. Just cut out anything that is sensitive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I edited the question and added the full C# code.
Unfortunately I do no have the code that was used to build the C++ dll. Also, I am not allowed to share the .dll file or parts of it. The (I guess) relevant part of the header file can be found in the question. Unfortunately I am not allowed to post the the full .h file.
Hope that helps. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @luk: I can save you some number of combinations to try out by assuring you that `[In]` is not wanted here.  Is this x86 or x64 code or some other architecture?  Some care about calling conventions a lot more than others.  `WINAPI` should set you up with stdcall as your p/invoke already specifies.

Comment: Build a simple dll yourself with that spec. And see how it goes. If you want help you'll need to give us more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could determine the problem.

In order to check the data types of the parameters and the return value, I used the decompiler *Snowman* on the dll. It looked like the dll only defines interfaces, and that the implementations are in another dll file which the developer forgot to send in first place.

Once the second .dll file is stored in the runtime folder of my program, the function call works. I also want to mention that the call works with and without `[In]` parameter attributes.

While I don't know the exact reason for the thrown exception `AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory...` (I think another exception could fit better here), I am happy that the issue could be solved.

Thanks to *Ben Voigt* and *David Heffernan* for their comments!